# Prove the given transformation of a Markov Chain is a Markov Chain

Tags: conditional-probability, markov-process

Let $\{X_n:n=0,1,\dots\}$ be a discrete time Markov chain on state space $S$. We define $Y_n$ as the following:
$$Y_n=(X_n, X_{n+1})$$
Prove that $\{Y_n:n=0,1,\dots\}$ is a discrete time Markov chain

My attempt:

$$P(Y_n = (j_n,k_n) | Y_{n-1}=(j_{n-1},k_{n-1}),\dots,Y_0 = (j_0,k_0))$$
$$=P(X_n=j_n,X_{n+1}=k_n|X_{n-1}=j_{n-1},X_n=k_{n-1},\dots,X_0 = j_0,X_1=k_0)$$
Here is where I am slightly confused. Would it be valid to use implications of Markov's property and simply get:
$$P(X_n=j_n,X_{n+1}=k_n|X_{n-1}=j_{n-1},X_n=k_{n-1})=P(Y_n=(j_n,k_n)|Y_{n-1}=(j_{n-1},k_{n-1}))$$
This seems like I am playing too fast and loose with the property however.

Comment: You could break$$P(X_n=j_n,X_{n+1}=k_n|X_{n-1}=j_{n-1},X_n=k_{n-1},\cdots)$$as\begin{align}P(X_n=j_n&|X_{n-1}=j_{n-1},X_n=k_{n-1},\cdots)\\&P(X_{n+1}=k_n|X_n=j_n,,X_{n-1}=j_{n-1},X_n=k_{n-1},\cdots)\end{align}

Comment: @Xi'an I tried doing that but the double $X_n$'s confused me somewhat. Can I just apply Markov property with that expression, get the product, and then translate it back to $Y_n$?

Comment: The double $X_n=$ is not an issue as the probability only makes sense when $j_n=k_{n-1}$ and so on.

Comment: @Xi'an in that case, is it acceptable to simply remove one of the $X_n$'s, assuming $j_n = k_{n-1}$?

Comment: yes this is correct.